# Lumen testing with PHPUnit showing too much assertions with only 2 tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

My test is working fine, but when I read this [article](https://stackify.com/unit-testing-basics-best-practices/), it's mention

> One Assert Per Test Method

and I think my test is making too much assertions, here is my testing code:

```
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class GuestTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    /** @test */
    public function guest_can_register()
    {
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/register', [
            "name" => "Khrisna Gunanasurya",
            "email" => "khrisnagunanasurya@gmail.com",
            "password" => "adminadmin",
            "password_confirmation" => "adminadmin"
        ]);

        $response
                ->seeStatusCode(HttpStatus::$CREATED)
                ->seeJsonStructure([
                    "data" => [
                        "type",
                        "id",
                        "attributes" => [
                            'name',
                            'email'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function registered_guest_can_login()
    {
        $this->post('/register', [
            "name" => "Khrisna Gunanasurya",
            "email" => "khrisnagunanasurya@gmail.com",
            "password" => "adminadmin",
            "password_confirmation" => "adminadmin"
        ]);

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/login', [
            'email' => 'khrisnagunanasurya@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'adminadmin'
        ]);

        $response
                ->seeStatusCode(HttpStatus::$OK)
                ->seeJsonStructure([
                    'data' => [
                        'type',
                        'attributes' => [
                            'token',
                            'token_type',
                            'expires_in'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
    }
}
```

So what I want to ask, is my testing return too much assertions for those simple test? as I realize that `seeJsonStructure()` is calling many assertions depends on the nested array structures, and if my test unit makes too much assertions will creates a problem in the future when there are lots of test files?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: The whole "One assertion per test" thing is more of a guideline than something that will actually cause issues. The nice thing about it is that when a test fails you know exactly what went wrong. If you have 100 assertions in 1 test it might be harder to find. In general I wouldn't worry about it to much.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the contents of the assertJsonStructure you can see how this function works, It basically iterates over all keys and asserts against the response. so in this case

```
public function assertJsonStructure(array $structure = null, $responseData = null){
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($key, $responseData);
            $this->assertJsonStructure($structure[$key], $responseData[$key]);
        } else {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($value, $responseData);
        }
    }
}
```

So you have 6 assertions which are generated by the assertJsonStructure and one more by the seeStatusCode. which it'll be a total of 7 assertions, you have two tests which sum of them is 14.